# Solving LR Circuit with Laplace Transform

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance, laplace-transform

I have a RLC circuit where the capacitor is connected in parallel with a resistance and inductance in series. The battery is connected "in parallel" with the capacitor and the RL branches. At t=0 the battery is disconnected from the circuit. I need to find the voltage across each element using the Laplace transform.

Here’s what I did:

$$ E = RI + L\frac{dI}{dt} $$

Taking the transform I arrive at:

$$\frac{E}{s} = R ℒ(I) + L(s ℒ(I) - I_0)$$

With $I(t=0) = I_0$
$$ => ℒ(I) = \frac{E/L}{s(R/L + s)} + \frac{I_0/L}{R/L + s} $$

Which gives

$$I(t) = \frac{E}{R} + [I_0 - \frac{E}{R}]e^{-Rt/L}$$

The thing is this result looks kind of weird and I feel like I did something wrong. Could anybody let know what I should do about this?

Comment: I don't see a term for capacitance anywhere, where did it go?

Comment: The voltage across the capacitance is the same as that across the R and L branch,

Comment: @Y2H - So you're saying (and your final equation above is saying) that the value of the capacitor in the circuit doesn't matter? Think about that. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

You got the very first equation wrong. The equation

$$E = RI + L\frac{dI}{dt}$$

would describe the time evolution of the *inductor's* current for $t<0$, not for $t>0$.

For $t<0$, one usually assumes that the circuit is at steady-state: this assumption is used to calculate the initial conditions, in this case, the voltage across the capacitor and the current through the inductor. The initial conditions are thus $v_C(0+)=v_C(0-)=E$, for the capacitor voltage $v_C(t)$,  and $i_L(0+)=i_L(0-)=E/R$, for the inductor current $i_L(t)$, where $v_C(0-) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0^-} v_C(t)$, $v_C(0+) =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} v_C(t)$, etc. Recall that the voltage across a capacitor and the current through an inductor cannot change instantaneously.

For $t>0$ you should write the differential equation associated to the circuit realized at $t>0$, which is composed of three series-connected elements, and then transform it in the Laplace domain with the initial conditions I described in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Hi, if you replace $E$ with $v_C$ in my answer, we are proceeding likewise. You will still get the same weird function for $I(t)$.

Comment: @Y2H No, $v_C$ is a function of time and you get a second-order differential equation.